# Getting valid URL from user input

Tags: c#, validation

I have a dialog which populates my `ConnectionStringData` object with the URL of the service that I'm trying to connect to. I then consume that URL with the following property:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Where the Service is located.
    /// </summary>
    public string ServiceLocation
    {
        get
        {
            string fullUrl = ConnectionStringData.Location.Trim();

            if (fullUrl.EndsWith("/"))
            {
                fullUrl += "Routes";
            }
            else
            {
                fullUrl += "/Routes";
            }

            Uri uri = null;

            if(Uri.TryCreate(fullUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
            {
                return uri.ToString();
            }

            throw new UriFormatException(String.Format("{0} is an invalid url", fullUrl));
        }
    }
```

Should I be doing work like this in the getter? Can I do this better?

Comment: I'm concerned by the exception in the getter. This indicates that something uncontrollable by the caller is getting thrust in their lap. FXCop agrees: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386039.aspx

Comment: You are bang on the money. I'm having to work in a very flaky legacy application so I have to step carefully at every step. I will take the advice of @Abbas and rework it on the consumption side.

Comment: You don't need to initialize `uri` to `null`, `out` will take care of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A much more readable version would be

```
public string ServiceLocation
{
    get
    {
        string fullUrl = ConnectionStringData.Location.Trim().TrimEnd('/') + "/Routes";

        Uri uri = null;

        if (Uri.TryCreate(fullUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
        {
            return uri.ToString();
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, I prefer this style as opposed to the additional ternary. You've used backslashes however which is correctly for folder path's but not URL's. :D

Comment: Any reason especially for a new char[] when you can just pass in: '/'  to TrimEnd.

Comment: Not really, intellisense said char[] so I used it ;-)

Comment: Be aware that this behaves differently when the original string ends with multiple `/`s, thought I guess such URLs should be pretty rare.

Answer (score 5):

This piece:

```
if (fullUrl.EndsWith("/"))
{
    fullUrl += "Routes";
}
else
{
    fullUrl += "/Routes";
}
```

can be rewritten to:

```
fullUrl += fullUrl.EndsWith("/") ? "Routes" : "/Routes";
```

or:

```
if (!fullUrl.EndsWith("/"))
    fullUrl += "/";
fullUrl += "Routes";
```

Since you're using the `TryCreate` method, there's no need to throw an exception. You just have to notify the caller whether the conversion succeeded or not. Plus, throwing an exception in a get statement is bad practice. This results in following:

```
if (Uri.TryCreate(fullUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
    return uri.ToString();
//if no succesful creation:
return String.Empty;
```

If you do want to throw an exception, use a try/catch block and a regular Uri constructor. This should be placed in a method and not in the get statement then:

```
try
{
    uri = new Uri(fullUrl, UriKind.Absolute);
    return uri.ToString();
}
catch (UriFormatException ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

My favor would still be with the `TryCreate` resulting in following final code:

```
public string ServiceLocation
{
    get
    {
        var fullUrl = ConnectionStringData.Location.Trim();
        fullUrl += fullUrl.EndsWith("/") ? "Routes" : "/Routes";

        Uri uri = null;

        if (Uri.TryCreate(fullUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
            return uri.ToString();
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to initialize it with null, that value is never used.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359732/why-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-omit-curly-braces regarding your curly braces. Plugins like `StyleCop` specifically flag this structure

Comment: @ANeves please tell us why?

Comment: Also shouldn't it be `fullUrl = ConnectionStringData.Location.Trim();`

Comment: @danrhul fixed `fullUrl`. Didn't know that about StyleCop, thought it was just a matter of style.

Comment: @dit you initialize with null, then immediately use it as an [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) parameter, which overrides the value. So the null value will always be overwritten without a chance to be used. (Quote from MSDN: `Although variables passed as out arguments do not have to be initialized before being passed, the called method is required to assign a value before the method returns.`)

Comment: There is no reason to catch an exception if you're going to immediately rethrow it. Just get rid of the whole `try`-`catch`.